# handling events before back button is clicked

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to find out whether the back button (Navigation bar) is clicked for a particular view ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I didn't try this myself.
I don't know of a way to intercept the click on the button. What "might" work is the following: There is the [UINavigationBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationBarDelegate), which contains the navigationBar:shouldPopItem: event. This event is called before a navigationItem is removed from the stack of your navigationBar, so if you handle this event, you might be able to do whatever you want to archive.

Comment: The OP doesn't state whether they're using a navigation controller or not. If not, Phlibbo's suggestion is a good one; however, if there's a nav controller involved then I don't think hooking into the nav bar delegate is a good idea since it will probably break the nav controller. In that case, a possible option would be to use the navigationController:willShowViewController:animated: method in UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

"handling events before" suggests you want to clean up or save state before the user leaves the view. In that case, I'd use viewWillDisappear: or viewDidDisappear:. If you need to distinguish between navigating back and navigating "forwards" (e.g. pushing a VC, or presenting a modal VC), you *might* be able to do something like:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (!self.parentViewController)
  {
     // back button pressed/modal VC dismissed/etc, hopefully
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but my understanding is that "Will"-methods are called before the VC hierarchy is changed, and "Did"-methods are called afterwards.

If you're saving state, you should also handle UIApplicationWillEnterBackgroundNotification.